# Alternative expression of equality other then "wie"

Tags: comparison

I would like know are there other words to express thing's equality rather than "wie". Following are translated like in examples but in some "wie" is missing, are there other comperative words like in English.

> Quiet as a mouse=> Mäuschenstill
>
> like a duck out of water => wie eine Ente ausser dem Wasser
>
> good as gold =>gut wie Gold
>
> old as the hills=>steinalt

For example how could I say "gut wie Gold" in another words, I actually want to use a comperative word like "wie" or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gleich und artig werden häufiger verwendet, um Gleichheit oder Gleichartigkeit auszudrücken:

> Katzengleich bewegte sie sich auf ihn zu. 
>   Es war ein erdrutschartiger Sieg.

Speziell bezogen auf "Gut wie Gold" fehlt mir der konkrete Kontext. Gold ist wertvoll, eine Farbe, aber gut? Gut wofür? Wann Gold geht, und wann eher nicht, scheint mir ziemlich idiomatisch zu sein. Ein Kind kann goldig lächeln. Ein Rat ist Gold wert.